# Code for drag and drop c# controls in to a form

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

i want a code snippet for dragging controls and dropping them to a Panel and placing them back...as needed.how can i get the controls property same as used in vs,i am using vs2010 and c# web application.i want the functionality to be as in as when we design a form.pls help..

Comment: why not just use VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

Create the control in a projetct with add to solution --> user control or component
Add the control to the toolbox via the Context Menu-->choose Items and select your control (do not forget to compile once finished ;-) )

All public properties will be available to edit in VS, there are also some attributes to control acces to the properties (but I can't remember them now).

hth

Mario

Comment: i  need the controls to be added to the panel,not to the vs.so please tel me how to add controls to the panel